# For loop math quiz generator, loop not repeating

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested

So I have an assignment in which I am supposed to generate a five-question math quiz with random numbers, and I am supposed to assign math operators with 0-2 with certain math properties, in a `for` loop. I am at my wits end here; I don't understand why it's not looping to repeat again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MathQuizS2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int first, second, sum;
        int attempt, diff, mult;
        int op;
        int total;
        final int correctMax = 5;
        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        double grade;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        op = generator.nextInt(3);
        first = generator.nextInt(11);

        second = generator.nextInt(11);

        sum = first + second;
        diff = first - second;
        mult = first * second;

        {
            for (total=0; total<=correctMax; total++)
            {
                if (op == 0)
                    System.out.println(" What is the sum of " + first + " + " + second + " ? ");

                attempt = scan.nextInt();

                if (sum == attempt) {
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                    correct++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect the sum is " + sum);
                    incorrect++;
                }

                if (op == 1)
                    System.out.println(" What is the difference between " + first + "-" + second + " ? ");

                attempt = scan.nextInt();

                if (diff == attempt) {
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                    correct++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect the difference is " + diff);
                    incorrect++;
                }

                if (op == 2)
                    System.out.println(" What is the product of " + first + " * " + second + " ? ");

                attempt = scan.nextInt();

                if (mult == attempt) {
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                    correct++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect the product is " + mult);
                    incorrect++;
                }
                total = 5;
            }
        }
        grade = (double) correct/5 * 100;
        System.out.println(" You got " + correct + " correct and " + incorrect + " incorrect of 5 questions, your grade is " + grade + "%");
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end of the first iteration of the for loop, you are assigning total = 5. At the start of next iteration total is incremented to 6, which is greater than correctMax. Hence you come out of the for loop. Are you sure your logic is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure whats wrong here. I took out the total=5; because maybe its in the wrong spot, but now it only evaluates one if . What is it that I need to fix?

Comment: Ok when i put { after the first nested if statement and close it after the else-it will only evaluate that question 5 times in the loop. if i put it after the first if statement, then it says my variables are not initalized. I want it to evaluate all 3 questions, and the last 2 randomly. Also, it is possible for the if statement to generate new numbers each time?  It uses the same numbers it generates the first time.

Answer (score 3):

In the `if (op...` constructs, only the next statement (in this case until semicolon, the next line), that is, the `println` statement is affected by the condition, not the following lines, `attempt = scan.nextInt();` and so on. They are unconditionally executed. That is not the original intent according to the original indentation of the source code.

```
            if (op == 0)
                System.out.println(" What is the sum of " + first + " + " + second + " ? ");

            attempt = scan.nextInt();

            if (sum == attempt) {
                System.out.println("You are correct");
                correct++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect the sum is " + sum);
                incorrect++;
            }
```

Use {} in the `if` constructs if you want all the lines to be affected by those conditions:

```
            if (op == 0) {
                System.out.println(" What is the sum of " + first + " + " + second + " ? ");

                attempt = scan.nextInt();

                if (sum == attempt) {
                    System.out.println("You are correct");
                    correct++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect the sum is " + sum);
                    incorrect++;
                }
            }
```

This is one of the reasons why most coding standards make {} mandatory.

Comment: Ok when i put { after the first nested if statement and close it after the else-it will only evaluate that question 5 times in the loop. if i put it after the first if statement, then it says my variables are not initalized. I want it to evaluate all 3 questions, and the last 2 randomly. Also, it is possible for the if statement to generate new numbers each time? It uses the same numbers it generates the first time

Answer (score 1):

You write `total=5;` at the end the for, cancel it. And you have { and this } before and after the for.